# Not able to go into signup method on slim index.php

Tags: php, json, postman, slim

I think I am running into a similar issue. I am getting the error:

> Call to undefined method Slim\Router::setCacheFile()

I am calling this from Postman:

```
127.0.0.1:8080/php-slim/signup
```

My post method in slim index.php is defined as:

Trying to send data from postman, and have it uploaded into localhost db, but seems like once it reaches index.php, it never goes into the function.

Looking forward to your help

This is the code on index.php

```
 <?php
    ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
    require 'C:\xampp\htdocs\php-slim\vendor\autoload.php';
    require 'config.php';
    require 'Slim/Slim.php';
    \Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
    $app = new \Slim\App();

    $app->post("/signup", function() {

        $request = \slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
        $data = json_decode($request->getBody());

        $fname=$data->fname;
        $lname=$data->lname;
        $username=$data->username;
        $password=$data->password;

        try {   
                $db = getDB();

                /*Inserting user values*/
                $sql1="INSERT INTO users(username,password,fname,lname)VALUES(:username,:password,:fname,:lname)";
                $stmt1 = $db->prepare($sql1);
                $stmt1->bindParam("username", $username,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt1->bindParam("password", $password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt1->bindParam("fname", $fname,PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt1->bindParam("lname", $lname,PDO::PARAM_STR);

                $db = null;

                if($userData){
                   $userData = json_encode($userData);
                    echo '{"userData": ' .$userData. '}';
                } else {
                   echo '{"error":{"text":"Enter valid data"}}';
                }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
           echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
        }
    });     
    $app->run();
```

Comment: There is too much lacking information here. We need to see the relevant code in order to help you. It appears to be an autoloading or namespace issue.

Comment: Please have a look at the code snippet of the index.php

Comment: Could you also provide the entire error output including the file and line #?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's somewhat unclear why you're getting that error, it looks like your are not including/loading the Slim dependencies.

I don't know what version of Slim you're using, but make sure you have also loaded all the required packages. You can get this for your specific version from https://packagist.org/packages/slim/slim. Using composer is nice because it manages this for you.

```
pimple/pimple: ^3.0
psr/http-message: ^1.0
nikic/fast-route: ^1.0
container-interop/container-interop: ^1.2
psr/container: ^1.0
```

Once everything is in place, try changing your code to this:

```
// I believe you need this object to use the request method
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;

$app = new \Slim\App();

$app->post("/signup", function(Request $request) {

    // not needed
    // $request = \slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();

    // no need to decode the request body, it's not json format
    // $data = json_decode($request->getBody());

    // do it this way instead. Will be array not object I believe
    $data = $request->getParsedBody();

    $fname = $data['fname'];

    ....

});
```

Comment: I have installed php slim ^3.0 using composer,

Comment: And what is the result?